# How can we make the server overloaded?

Tags: rhel

In college systems, the server running the rhel, and the nodes which are used by the students are running the windows xp are connected to the server by LAN cables.

But I want to slowdown the server, so the request to the server, which is serving the students command request through terminal will response very slow. How this can be done?

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you want to slow down the server in the first place? If this was about slowing down the network traffic, I suppose you could rate-limit outgoing TCP packets using iptables (possibly on specific ports only), but that'd still leave the server running at its normal speed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what protocol your clients & server are using to communicate, but as far as overloading the server, you could easily run a script that's nothing more than in infinite loop.

In python, this would be as simple as logging in and running the python interpreter, then entering

```
while True: pass
```

If you open as many terminals as you have CPU's, then the server should be pretty bogged down, though that won't necessarily make your network responses noticeably slower.  (To see the number of CPUs, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`)

You might have more success if you tell us more about your problem: what protocol is this?  HTTP?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Each node is using telnet to communicate with server. yes I tried with infinite loop but it's not efficient to do so.